# Where to write a interrupt handler and how to register with kernel in linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, interrupt

Scenario : Client is sending a data and the server is receving the data from client via ethernet layer (udp). When the server receives a data from the client on the ip layer (kernel). It interrupts the kernel and kernel as to execute the data by the client, so I want to create a interrupt service function to catch the interrupt from the network service card.

I can't write kernel modules (the kernel is not open) and you have real-time in user-space for QNX.
However I can write code using RTLinux (real time linux) in kernel space and with kernel modules.

Where to write a interrupt handler and how to register with kernel in linux ??

Comment: If you want get interrupts when some packet arrives from client, you can easily do it with pcap library.

Comment: I am new doing this kind of adventure. So could you please explain more about this - where do i find the pcap library in kernel ??

Comment: Basically pcap is a user space and a very powerful library to work on all kinds of stuff on traffic received by your network card. You do not need to go in to kernel while using pcap.

Comment: where can i find the pcap library ?? If i am not worng then I will add the interrupt handler in pcap - is it right ??

Comment: http://www.tcpdump.org/#latest-release for Linux and https://www.winpcap.org/install/ for windows. Yes you can add you handler fucntion while using pcap.

Comment: thank you very much!!! how and where to add the interrupt handler function (this is created by me) in the kernel module ??

Comment: As mentioned above, libpcap is user space thingy and thus not usable in a kernel module. The question you should be asking, I think, is: "Why do I want to do this thing in a kernel module? Is it necessary to do it there or could I be doing this same stuff in user space?"

Comment: my supervisor said that I have to write a interrupt handler code in kernel mode and not in usermode. later I have to compile the kernel. Is it the right way ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for you to do that is not to register a interrupt handler, but to use an existing mechanism called Linux netfilter hooks. You can define a callback function which will be executed when a packet reaches one the netfilter chains.

Some documentation: http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-hacking-HOWTO-3.html